# Breaking out/ bypassing promise chain in node Js

Tags: node.js, promise

I am new to nodeJs and trying to develop a functionality. As per this I need to fetch a data that can be present in one of the 4 places in different form and I need to return a mapped object for it from where ever I found it first.
So lets consider an example, I am trying to find a carnivorous animal in zoo (Tiger,Lion, Leopard) and there are different handlers present to find each one of them. when ever I find find animal I need to wrap it in CarnivorousWrapper and return it and skip all below in ladder (so if Tiger found first don't find any other animal).
One way to achieve is through call back hell like below

```
function getCarnivorous () {
  return getTiger()
    .then(tigerResponse => {
      if (tigerResponse) {
        return carnivorousAdapter(tigerResponse);
      } else {
        return getLion()
          .then(lionResponse => {
            if (lionResponse) {
              return carnivorousAdapter(lionResponse);
            } else {
              return getLeopard()
                .then(lionResponse => {
                  if (lionResponse) {
                    return carnivorousAdapter(lionResponse);
                  } else {
                    throw NotFoundException('Animal not found');
                  }
                });
            }
          });
      }
    });
}
```

I need to understand if this can be done in better way something like Promise ladder and how to exit out of it as soon as tiger has been found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the es6 async/await feature (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to have a more readable code then now:

```
async function getCarnivorous () {
  let response = await getTiger()
  if(!response) {
    response = await getLion()
  }
  if(!response) {
    response = await getLeopard()
  }
  if(!response) {
    throw NotFoundException('Animal not found')
  }
  return carnivorousAdapter(response)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response ! I thought about it but I have read at several places not to use async/await much as it introduces blocking.

Comment: As far as I know it shouldn't. Because async/await does nothing else then wait for the promise to resolve and storing the resolved value into the variable.
If the promise rejects. it throws an error. So it would be wise to wrap the call to `getCarnivorous` into an try/catch for proper error handling

Comment: @ShailendraChoudhary - Whatever you read about await causing blocking is wrong.  It does not block.  It is not less efficient than `.then()`.  In fact, in many ways, it is more efficient than `.then()` because it allows you to write code more simply, particularly conditional asynchronous code such as is present in your question.  This answer is the correct approach.

Comment: @jfriend00 It has a little overhead compared to `.then()` because the awaiter has a loop which checks periodically if the promise resolved. Especially when you write typescript and transpile it down to es5.
But it is negligible in most usecases.

Comment: @mathewmeconry - Native `await` has no loop - it's entirely event driven.  In fact, the JS language/promise spec was modified specifically to enhance the performance of `await`.  If some transpiler down to ES5 is using a loop, that's bad code.  There are MORE, not less opportunities for the interpreter to optimize `await` than `.then()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 nice didn't know about this. thanks for the heads up